# clearing one nested text input field in a list returns an error - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm displaying records from a DB on a page with each having a textbox to it so users can give feedback. When a user types in and then decides to clear everything in the textbox, it produces an error

```
Invariant violation: Text strings must be rendered in a <Text> component
```

CONTAINER

```
setComment= (commentValue, postId) => {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    const newPost = posts.map(post => {
       if (postId === post.id){
         return {
           ...post,
           commentValue: commentValue === null || commentValue === undefined ? '' : commentValue
         }
       }

       return post
     });

     this.setState({
       posts: newPost
     })
}
```

VIEW

```
<TextInput
           onChangeText={value => onSetComment(value, item.id)}
            label='Write Comment'
            underlineColor="#36a"
            value={item.commentValue}
            style={{backgroundColor:'#fff', width:'90%'}}
          />

{
  item.commentValue &&
  <Icon
  //  iconStyle={[(isEnabled=== true) ? styles.likedColor : styles.unLikedColor]}
    iconStyle={styles.likedColor}
    name='md-arrow-round-forward'
    type='ionicon'
    color='#999'
    onPress={() => {onCommentPost(item)}}
  />
}
```

Comment: try console logging `newPost` before setting it as a state.

Comment: Can you add all code in the component?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you set `posts` to only **one** updated post?

```
this.setState({
  posts: newPost
})
```

Comment: when I take out this bit, it works perfectly, but as you can use I've updated the questions. When i take out this.setState({
  posts: newPost
}) the submit button too doesn't show up

Comment: You need to reset the value of the textinput if the character is equal to 0

If (commentValue.length === 0) { this.setState({ commentValue: ‘’ }) }